# Retorno de mensagens do método

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, mvc

Recentemente comecei a estudar mais sobre a orientação a objetos, porém a maioria dos exemplos são muito genéricos e só para fins didáticos.

O ponto que estou com dúvida está em relação ao retorno dos métodos. Em um cenário como da autenticação de usuários, diversas exceções(erros em comandos SQL, erros em servidores ) podem ocorrer. Sendo assim, o método autenticar não pode simplesmente retornar um boolean, pois não seria possível identificar o contexto daquela resposta.

No código fonte abaixo estou tentando implementar o método autenticar. Atualmente ele retorna somente um boolean, porém preciso incluir tratamentos para erros que possam ocorrer na comunicação com o banco de dados, ou até a mesmo uma mensagem informando que o usuário está bloqueado.

```php
class Sessao {

    public function autenticar($conexao, $usuario, $senha) : boolean {

        $sql = "exec sys_autenticar_usario :usuario, :senha, '', 1";
        $params = array(
            "usuario" => $usuario,
            "senha" => $senha,
        );
        $result = $conexao->executarSQL($sql, $params, "");

        if ( count($result) > 0 ){
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

Gostaria de saber qual a forma mais apropriada para retornar essas mensagens.

Comment: tem algum código? usa algum framework? tem um contexto? é muito ampla a sua duvida precisa de um foco especifico

Comment: "*a maioria dos exemplos são muito genéricos*", sim, isso acontece porque a Orientação a Objetos é um (pseudo-)paradigma e não determina, por essência, como será a implementação.

Comment: o mais correto é lançar exceções com os erros, o retorno do método deve apenas sinalizar que o usuário foi autenticado, de preferência não retornando boolean, mas informações do próprio usuário para você utilizar posteriormente. essa questão não é de orientação a objetos apesar de envolver alguns dos conceitos.

Comment: Você tem razão, quase tudo o que se usa por aí ensinando OOP não serve pra muita coisa a não ser ensinar errado por usar exemplos artificiais. OOP é fazer algo real acontecer, não é entender um mecanismo, que é a forma como ensinam. Muitas pessoas tem opiniões bem erradas sobre como deveria fazer isto porque aprenderam errado. Sua pergunta é muito genérica.

Comment: Adicionei um código fonte com uma breve descrição em relação ao cenário citado.

Comment: esse código `$conexao->executarSQL` vem da onde? pelo que eu pude entender é dele que pode ocorrer erros de conectividade! o outro retorno de usuário bloqueado tem que vir da sua procedure (acho que é um procedure ali).?

Comment: se estiver usando pdo, pode configurar para gerar exceções, depois você captura com try catch: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8992795/set-pdo-to-throw-exceptions-by-default